# Memory Allocation in C and passing multiple numbers

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how'd I'd accomplish a task and am looking for help.

So, I need to use a function that'll find a pair of numbers (to be allocated dynamically) that meets a condition and returns a pointer to it.

Here's what I have:

```
int* f_cubes_sum(int n)
{
    //Declaring array
    int *numSet;
    numSet = (int *)malloc(2); // Only two because I'm looking for a pair
    //Declaring variables
    int sum = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    bool results = false;



    while (b < n && results == false)
    {
        while (a < n)
        {
            sum = a^3 + b^3;
            if (sum == n)
            {
                results = true;
            }
            else
            {
                a = a + 1;
            }

            sum = 0;
        }

        if (results = false)
        {
            a = 0;
            b = b + 1;
        }
    }

    if (results = false)
    {
        a = NULL;
        b = NULL;

    }

    numSet[0] = a;
    numSet[1] = b;
    free(numSet);
    return numSet;
}
```

And in my main function, how would I access both numbers?

Thank you for your time

Comment: `malloc(2)` allocates 2 bytes; you need `malloc(2 * sizeof(*numSet))`. But if you need 2 ints locally, why not use an automatic array?

Comment: You can't free the allocated memory, and then return a pointer to it!

Comment: For a start, `main` can't use the memory block if you already freed it.

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your problem cause I barely read it, but in C, `=` is assignment, not equality.  You need to replace your `if (something = something)` with `if (something == something)`.  Rookie mistake ;)

Comment: Does anyone know what's up with everyone casting `malloc`'s result in C? This is often done by complete beginners which suggests they're taught to do that by their professors... OP, FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605994

Comment: Oh, and `a^3` isn't the cube of `a`. That's `a*a*a`. ( `^` is the xor or exclusive or operator in C.)

Comment: This starts to feel like an exam. "Find the ten errors in the code. You get one point for each error you have found."

Comment: @szczurcio There are two professors at my university that do this. I think a lot of people who started with C++ just assume C++ is a superset of C. It makes me cringe a little, since there's not stdlib.h included. I hope that was in the actual code.

Comment: Just so you know, comments like `declaring variables` and `declaring array` aren't useful in the slightest; your comments should describe what the function does at a high level. `a = a + 1;` is equivalent to `a++` or `a += 1`. You don't have to compare a boolean against false, you can just do `if (!result)`.

Comment: For the particular case of returning two numbers, [returning them in a struct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25381839/841108) may be much more efficient

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a function that determines whether a number can be written a the sum of two cubes and if so, it should yield the two numbers whose cubes are summed. Basically you need:

- an information on whether `n` can be written as `a³ + b³` and
- if so, the values of `a` and `b`.

You can use your approach of allocating an array of two integers and return that on success and `NULL` on failure. If you do so, you should allocate the array only if you have a result:

```
int *f_cubes_sum(int n)
{
    int a, b;

    // logic to work out whether a³ + b³ == n
    if (a*a*a + b*b*b == sum) {
        int *res = malloc(2 * sizeof(*res));

        res[0] = a;
        res[1] = b;

        return res;
    }

    // no solution found
    return NULL;
}
```

The drawback here is that the calling code has to free the returned pointer:

```
int *res = f_cubes_sum(2778);

if (res) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", res[0], res[1]);
    free(res);
}
```

Another approach is to pass in an array that your code has to fill and indicate success or failure with a boolean return value:

```
bool f_cubes_sum(int n, int res[2])
{
    int a, b;

    // logic to work out whether a³ + b³ == n
    if (a*a*a + b*b*b == sum) {
        res[0] = a;
        res[1] = b;

        return true;
    }

    // no solution found
    return false;
}
```

Now the calling code has to provide the space for the result:

```
int res[2];

if (f_cubes_sum(2778, res)) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", res[0], res[1]);
}
```

Of course, because you are always dealing with two possible result values, you could also pass pointers to these values instead of passing an array. Here's a variant of your function that does this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool f_cubes_sum(int n, int *pa, int *pb)
{
    int a = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        int a3 = a*a*a;

        if (a3 > n) break;

        int b = cbrt(n - a3) + 0.5;
        int b3 = b*b*b;

        if (a3 + b3 == n) {
            *pa = a;
            *pb = b;
            return true;
        }

        a++;
    }

    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    int n = 35001;

    if (f_cubes_sum(n, &a, &b)) {
        printf("%d^3 + %d^3 == %d\n", a, b, n);
    } else {
        printf("Nothing found for %d.\n", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also note what commenters have alreadey pointed out:

- In C, `=` assigns, `==` compares. Unfortunately, an assignment inside an `iF` condition is valid C: It will assign the value and then test it, entering the clause if it isn't 0 or false. Therefore `if (x = false)` never enters the `if` clause. Switch on warnings to carch such mistakes.
- The `^` operator isn't the power operator, it is the bitwise xor operator. Raising a number `a` to the power of `b` is done with the floating-point function `pow(a, b)`. If the exponent is a known small integer, it is usually better to write the multiplication explicitly. Thus, `pow(a, 3)` is rendered better as `a*a*a`.
- When allocating memory, be sure the make enough room for the desired type. Also don't use `free`d pointers; the memory they point to is invalid.

Comment: Looks like a stray formatting issue in 3rd paragraph from bottom (the *antepenultimate* paragraph - for Leffler's benefit)

Comment: Oh, yes, those pesky backwards quotes. I usually manage go have one or two leaning the wrong way. And thanks for correcting the function call.